# weburl with special CSS in it?

Tags: css, url, browser

By adding the code `#:~:text=[TEXT TO HIGHLIGHT]` after a URL, the text is highlighted by browsers (I think all, except firefox).
For example, see how the "Top question" text is highlighted on the stackoverflow home page:
[https://stackoverflow.com/#:~:text=Top%20Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/#:%7E:text=Top%20Questions)

I think it's some kind of special CSS for browser.
Does anyone know how and where this feature is documented?

[image]

Comment: FWIW, this does absolutely zilch for me in both Safari and Chrome.

Comment: try editing the example url, removing "https://" before "stackoverflow.com/#:~:text=Top%20Questions", please, and then press return

Comment: try this: https://google.com/#:~:text=google
the word "google" in the upper left is highlighted

Comment: All of yours links don't work for me, but adding it to the current URL with some text that appears on this page works… Anyway, I linked to an explanation above.